# Select specific row Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, ant-design-blazor

I have to select **clicked** row and bind information only to that row. This is my function which shows me which row I clicked:

```
 void OnSelectedRow(RowData<Data> row)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"row {row.Data.dkUserName} was clicked.");
}
```

Now I need some if or smth to show me only specific information about that Username like First name, Last name, phone, email. This is my object

```
 Data d = new Data();
        d.dkId = Int16.Parse(dkId_content);
        d.dkCompanyName = dkCompanyName_content;
        d.dkStatus = dkStatus_content;
        d.dkAddress = dkAddress_content;
        d.dkUserName = dkUserName_content;
        d.dkFirstName = dkFirstname_content;
        d.dkLastName = dkLastName_content;
        d.dkEmail = dkEmail_content;
        d.dkPhoneNumber = dkPhone_content;
        data[i] = d;
```

This is UI:

```
<Modal Title="@title"
   Visible="@_visible"
   OnOk="@HandleOk"
   OnCancel="@HandleCancel"
   Footer=null>
   
<Table TItem="Data" DataSource="@data" OnRowClick="OnSelectedRow">
    <AntDesign.Column @bind-Field="@context.dkId" Sortable />
    <AntDesign.Column @bind-Field="@context.dkUserName" Sortable>
        <a>@context.dkUserName</a>
    </AntDesign.Column>
    <AntDesign.Column Title="Enable" Field="@context.dkEnable">
        <Switch @bind-Field="@context.dkEnable"></Switch>
    </AntDesign.Column>
    <ActionColumn Title="Action">
        <Space Size=@("middle")>
            <SpaceItem>
                <Button OnClick="@(()=>{ _visible2 = true; })">Info</Button>
            </SpaceItem>
        </Space>
    </ActionColumn>
</Table>
```

Inside this modal, you can see the button "Info". When click to the button it has to show information about a clicked row.

Here is UI of that modal:

```
<Modal Title="@title2"
   Visible="@_visible2"
   OnOk="@HandleOk2"
   OnCancel="@HandleCancel2"
   
   Style="width: 100%;"
   Footer=null>
  <Table TItem="Data" DataSource="@data">
      
    <AntDesign.Column @bind-Field="@context.dkUserName" Sortable>
        <a>@context.dkUserName</a>
    </AntDesign.Column>
    <AntDesign.Column @bind-Field="@context.dkFirstName" Sortable>
        <a>@context.dkFirstName</a>
    </AntDesign.Column>
    <AntDesign.Column @bind-Field="@context.dkLastName" Sortable>
        <a>@context.dkLastName</a>
    </AntDesign.Column>
    <AntDesign.Column @bind-Field="@context.dkEmail" Sortable>
        <a>@context.dkEmail</a>
    </AntDesign.Column>
    <AntDesign.Column @bind-Field="@context.dkPhoneNumber" Sortable>
        <a>@context.dkPhoneNumber</a>
    </AntDesign.Column>
    <AntDesign.Column @bind-Field="@context.dkStatus" Sortable>
        <a>@context.dkStatus</a>
    </AntDesign.Column>
    <AntDesign.Column Title="Intercept" Field="@context.dkEnable">
        <Switch @bind-Field="@context.dkEnable"></Switch>
    </AntDesign.Column>
    
   </Table>
```

Comment: Where and how do you want to show "only specific information"?  `OnSelectedRow(RowData<Data> row)` looks like you're using a third party component. 
 Which one?

Comment: I have modal with table, there i want to use

Comment: Still no clearer, you need to show more code.  You've shown an event handler and a data class, no one had any idea of what the UI looks like.

Comment: That's better.  However, I'm bowing out as I'm no expert in AntDesign components.